# Cannot convert csv file into point shapefile using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, convert, csv, arccatalog

I can import my **large** csv file into ArcGis Desktop and I can view it in Catalog and everything looks fine. When I go to 'create feature class' it does not recognize the column that I need to use for the z value. It is not an option I can pick.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop and trying to do this in Catalog.

---

This is what I get when I try to make the XY shapefile. No Z options.

Comment: Have you got any non-numerical values in this column?

Comment: Does your csv file contain headers (X,Y,Z) at the top row?

Comment: It does have headers. I actually got it to sort of work before but it only took 1 years worth of the data and left out the other 11! So the fact that it did work (sort of) once makes me think the columns themselves are OK.....

Comment: There are some non-numerical values in the z column where temperature was not recorded. They are NA. Should I change all those to 0?

Comment: @Jill the NA values are most likely the culprit I would change them to an integer value that you will recognize as null like 999. Zero works as long as you don't have any other zero values for temperature.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It doesn't seem to 'see' any data columns besides lat & long.

Comment: Please **edit** your post to include both your header row and a few sample rows of the data. It's possible you have an invalid field name. It's also possible that it isn't recognizing the data type correctly and you need a schema.ini file. When you say did one year and left out the other 11, is each year a row or a column? It's unclear how your data is organized.

Comment: Export csv to table and check field type for 'z' column

Comment: You cannot include screenshots in comments, only posts or answers. The screenshot must be a file (local or on the web - you can't just hit prnt scrn and paste from the clipboard) and there's a insert picture button above the body edit box when editing a post (edit button at lower left of your question, above the comments). If it's text you could also just paste the rows directly into the question rather than using a screenshot. I'm not sure why it would have partially worked - you should have either gotten nothing or a bunch of stacked points assuming same coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your table in the "Table of Contents" click "Display XY Data." Choose whichever fields map to X, Y, and Z, then choose your coordinate system. Right click the event layer, and export to your desired location.

[image: Display XY Data]

Comment: It does not give me the option of selecting anything for the z field. It has a <none>, lat or long which are the xy but the temperature field is not 'seen' even though when I preview the table it is there.

Comment: What version of ArcMap are you using? refer to my image, hopefully it looks similar.

Comment: I'm using 10.2 and was trying to do this in Catalog,not map. Hmm maybe I'll try that!

Comment: As I stated in the comments its likely that the non numerical values in the Z field are causing it to not be recognized as a usable Z value.

Comment: OK I will try changing them to 0s but it is strange that it worked before even if it only used 1 year of data. The year it did use had non-numeric values in the z column as well. THank you for the suggestion!

Comment: It still did not work :(. The program doesn't seem to be seeing any columns other than lat & long.

Comment: OK, I"m an idiot, I can't figure out how to insert a screen capture.

Comment: Chris, Each year is a row. Well, it's actually many rows.